# How can I set up an RSS feed to drip feed one new post per day from an existing blog?

Tags: rss

How can I set up an RSS feed to drip feed one new post per day from an existing blog?

So for example, I want to work my way through `http://1000awesomethings.com/`, but I only want to see one or two posts per day - is it possible for me to set up an [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feed (or some other way) that I can subscribe to, so that it shows me just one or two posts per day?

Answer (score 1):

This site looks like it will "play back" an RSS feed by converting it into a new RSS feed:
http://www.streamspigot.com/feed-playback/

Answer (score 0):

dlvr.it has a decent RSS app that allows you to adjust post setting exactly as you specify in your question. Options include trickle, where dlvr.it will post any new articles within a specified timeframe or, if you choose to just make one posting a day you can do so too. You can also tell dlvr.it to post the most recent, oldest or random post it comes across when it goes over your site.